# Why is part of my weight paint not being erased?

Tags: rigging, weight-painting, weight-paint-mode

Working with some controllers in my rig and trying to disconnect them from the mesh. The weight paint subtract mode works for other weight paint, but the toes just refuse to be erased. It stays red and connected to the bone, when I want it to be blue and disconnected, since I want a different bone to control it

I recorded what's happening so you can better understand: https://youtu.be/aOkRekrE2Hw

https://pasteall.org/blend/e511a099ae87479fa9d1ca0176fe26f4

Comment: hello could you please share your file: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.

Comment: Are you using autonormalize?  Are the verts in question weighted to any other bones?  If yes and no respectively, you can't subtract, because there is no other group to autonormalize the weights.

Comment: @Nathan Just unchecked autonormalize, and i was able to erase the red. That cause other unforeseen problems, but I'll continue to troubleshoot on my own. Thanks for the help!